# Combine BertForSequenceClassificaion with Additional Features

Tags: pytorch, bert, text-classification

I'm using BertForSequenceClassification + Pytorch Lightning-Flash for a text classification task.
I want to add additional features besides the text (e.g. categorical features). From what I understand, I need to override BertForSequenceClassification "forward" method and change the final classification layer (at least) to include the CLS vector + features vector. However, I didn't understand how I adapt the data loading procedure to this task - the text part is represented as input ids, and the rest supposed to be represented differently. Is there a simple way to combine text+features for Bert classification task?
Thank you!

Comment: why dont you feed bert output to another classifier which takes account of the categorical data as well. It is quite difficult to adjust ready-made models like Bert to account for this kind of data

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If I want to fine-tune the bert model itself - i.e. unfreeze bert layers during the classification learning procedure, is it possible to do it while "injecting" categorical features in a final layer?